# error in c code

Tags: c

i have a c code which gives me error that is segmented fault what that error means i don't get it. here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STREQUAL(a,b) (strcmp(a,b) == 0)

/* State of the 54-card deck.  This keeps a spare deck for copying
   into.  It also has three spare slots *behind* the start of the
   deck: two so the deck can be moved backward if a joker is moved
   from the bottom to the top in the first step, and one so that the
   reference to the card before the first joker always points
   somewhere even when there's a joker on the top of the pack. */

typedef struct SolState_t {
    int a, b;
    int *deck, *spare;
    int deck1[57], deck2[57];
} SolState_t ;

SolState_t state;

int verbose = 0;
int lastout, cocount;


#define JOKER_STEP(var,ovar) \
    (((var != 53) ? \
      (source[var] = source[var +1], var++) : \
      (source--, ovar++, source[0] = source[1], var = 1)), \
     ((var == ovar)?(ovar--):0))

/* Cycle the state for "rounds" outputs, skipping jokers
   as usual.  "lastout" is the last output, which is never a joker.

   If "rounds" is zero though, cycle the state just once, even
   if the output card is a joker. "lastout" may or may not be set.
   This is only useful for key setup.

   Note that for performance reasons, this updates the coincidence
   statistics under all circumstances, so they need to be set to zero
   immediately before the large batch run. */

static void cycle_deck(
    int rounds
)
{
    int *source, *s, *sb, *d;
    int lo, hi;
    int nlo, nhi, nccut;
    int output;

    do {
        assert(state.a != state.b);
        assert(state.deck[state.a] == 53);
        assert(state.deck[state.b] == 53);
        source = state.deck;
        JOKER_STEP(state.a,state.b);
        JOKER_STEP(state.b,state.a);
        JOKER_STEP(state.b,state.a);
        source[state.a] = 53;
        source[state.b] = 53;
        if (state.a < state.b) {
            lo = state.a;
            hi = state.b + 1;
        } else {
            lo = state.b;
            hi = state.a + 1;
        }
        nlo = 54 - hi;
        nhi = 54 - lo;
            /* We do both the triple cut and the count cut as one
               copying step; this means handling four separate cases. */
        nccut = source[lo -1];
        s = source;
        if (lo == 0) {
                /* There's a joker on the top of the pack.  This can
                   only happen in one exact circumstance, but when it
                   does nccount is wrong.  So we handle it specially. */
            assert(state.a == 0);
            assert(state.b == 2);
            d = &state.spare[51];
            sb = &source[3];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[0];
            sb = &source[54];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            state.a = 51;
            state.b = 53;
        } else if (nccut <= nlo) {
                /* The second cut is before the first joker. */
            d = &state.spare[nhi - nccut];
            sb = &source[lo -1];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            state.spare[53] = *s++;
            d = &state.spare[nlo - nccut];
            sb = &source[hi];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[53 - nccut];
            sb = &source[nccut + hi]; /* ccut */
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[0];
            sb = &source[54];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            state.a += nlo - nccut - lo;
            state.b += nlo - nccut - lo;
        } else if (nccut < nhi) {
                /* The second cut is between the two jokers */
            d = &state.spare[nhi - nccut];
            sb = &source[lo -1];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            state.spare[53] = *s++;
            d = &state.spare[53 - nccut + nlo];
            sb = &source[nccut - nlo + lo]; /* ccut */
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[0];
            sb = &source[hi];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[53 - nccut];
            sb = &source[54];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            if (state.a < state.b) {
                state.a = 53 - nccut + nlo;
                state.b = nhi - nccut -1;
            } else {
                state.b = 53 - nccut + nlo;
                state.a = nhi - nccut -1;
            }
        } else {
                /* The second cut is after the last joker. */
            d = &state.spare[53 - nccut + nhi];
            sb = &source[nccut - nhi]; /* ccut */
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[0];
            sb = &source[lo -1];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            state.spare[53] = *s++;
            d = &state.spare[53 - nccut + nlo];
            sb = &source[hi];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            d = &state.spare[53 - nccut];
            sb = &source[54];
            while(s < sb) {*d++ = *s++;}
            state.a += 53 - nccut + nlo - lo;
            state.b += 53 - nccut + nlo - lo;
        }
        source = state.deck;
        state.deck = state.spare;
        state.spare = source;
        output = state.deck[state.deck[0]];
        if (output >= 26) {
            if (output >= 52) {
                if (output > 52)
                    continue;
                output = 0;
            } else {
                output -= 26;
            }
        }
        cocount += (lastout == output);
        lastout = output;
        rounds--;
    } while (rounds > 0);
}

static void print_deck(
)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
    if (state.deck[i] < 53) {
      putchar(' ' + state.deck[i]);
    } else if (i == state.a) {
      putchar('U');
    } else {
      assert(i == state.b);
      putchar('V');
    }
  }
}

/* Key the deck with a passphrase. */

static void key_deck(
    char *key
)
{
    int i, kval, *tmp;

    state.deck = state.deck1 + 3;
    state.spare = state.deck2 + 3;
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        state.deck[i] = i+1;
    }
    state.deck[state.a = 52] = 53;
    state.deck[state.b = 53] = 53;
    for (; *key != '\0'; key++) {
        if ( *key >= 'A' && *key <= 'Z' ) {
            cycle_deck(0); /* Special value '0' is only useful here... */
                /* And now perform a second count cut based on the key letter */
            kval = *key - 'A' + 1;
            for (i = 0; i < 53; i++)
                state.spare[i] = state.deck[(i + kval) % 53];
            state.spare[53] = state.deck[53];
            if (state.a != 53)
                state.a = (state.a + 53 - kval) % 53;
            if (state.b != 53)
                state.b = (state.b + 53 - kval) % 53;
            tmp = state.deck;
            state.deck = state.spare;
            state.spare = tmp;
        if (verbose) {
            print_deck();
            printf(" after %c\n", *key);
        }
        }
    }
    /* These are touched by the keying: fix them. */
    lastout = 100; cocount = 0;
}

/* Encrypt a single character. */

static char encrypt_char(
    char char_in
)
{
    char char_out;

    cycle_deck(1);
    char_out = 'A' + (char_in - 'A' + lastout) % 26;
    if (verbose) {
        print_deck();
        printf(" %c -> %c\n", char_in, char_out);
    }
    return char_out;
}


int main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[]
)
{
    char **av = argv, *tmp;
    int slow_mode = 0;
    long rounds;

    /* Skip the name of the program */
    av++; argc--;
    if (argc  < 2) {
      printf("Usage: [flags] key message|len\n");
    }
    while (argc > 2) {
      if (STREQUAL(*av, "-v")) {
    verbose = 1;
      } else if (STREQUAL(*av, "-s")) {
    slow_mode = 1;
      } else {
    printf ("Unrecognised flag: %s\n", *av);
    exit(-1);
      }
      av++; argc--;
    }
    key_deck(av[0]);
    rounds = strtol(av[1], &tmp, 0);
    if (*tmp != '\0') {
      /* It's not a number - so it's a string! */
      char *text = av[1];
      int i = 0;

      for (; *text != '\0'; text++) {
    if (*text >= 'A' && *text <= 'Z') {
      if (i > 0 && (i % 5) == 0)
        putchar(' ');
      putchar(encrypt_char(*text));
      i++;
    }
      }
      while ((i % 5) != 0) {
    putchar(encrypt_char('X'));
    i++;
      }
      putchar('\n');
    } else {
      /* Treat it as a sequence of 'A's. */
      int i;

      if (rounds <= 0) {
    printf("Rounds number must be greater than zero\n");
    exit(-1);
      }
      if (verbose || slow_mode) {
    for (i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
      encrypt_char('A');
      } else {
    cycle_deck(rounds);
      }
      printf("Coincidences: %d / %ld\n", cocount, rounds -1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I hate when that happens.

Comment: Until you show some code we can think about the only solution I see for you is to hire a consultant for 100$/h to have a look at your code on site.

Comment: Please post what that code is. We are not psychic, we cannot find errors in code that we can't see. Also, please post what you have tried to take care of the problem yourself.

Comment: Yeah, posting the *entire code for your project* is guaranteed to be overkill. You need to isolate the problem down to a relatively small snippet of code. No one is going to read all of that to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: hmm okey but the problem is that i dont get where is it giving error as i am using gcc in linux if i have visual studio then should i get the line where am getting error.

Comment: Right, so you need a debugger. Stack Overflow is a poor replacement for a proper debugger.

Comment: hmm if i have the visual studio i could locate where it is giving me the error  but on gcc i am new and dont know how to debug it but thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Oversimplification, but one simple strategy for finding bugs: Keep deleting lines of code until the error goes away.  The line that you deleted last is the one with the error.

Answer (score 4):

[Segmentation fault.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Editing the answer in response to your edit, try using GDB:
run:
 gdb myapp.exe 
then give the command "start" and after that "step" until you hit the problem. It will help you narrow down the problem area to one particular function.

I should have mentioned that for full information when debugging, compile using the "-g " switch (using gcc). A full tutorial on GDB is available [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbuse.html)

Comment: thanks buddy it is really helpful am trying to find the error. thanks

Answer (score 4):

A [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) indicates a memory access violation. It is usually the result of dereferencing a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) or accessing an out of bounds array index when programming in C.

Try using [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to step through the program and determine where the segmentation fault occurs.