# getting error in c code

Tags: c, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I am getting the following error message:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x08048ff3 in key_deck (key=0x0) at c1.c:210 210  for (; *key != '\0'; key++) { (gdb)

This is my code:

```
static void key_deck(
    char *key
)
{
    int i, kval, *tmp;

    state.deck = state.deck1 + 3;
    state.spare = state.deck2 + 3;
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        state.deck[i] = i+1;
    }
    state.deck[state.a = 52] = 53;
    state.deck[state.b = 53] = 53;
    for (; *key != '\0'; key++) {
        if ( *key >= 'A' && *key <= 'Z' ) {
            cycle_deck(0); /* Special value '0' is only useful here... */
                /* And now perform a second count cut based on the key letter */
            kval = *key - 'A' + 1;
            for (i = 0; i < 53; i++)
                state.spare[i] = state.deck[(i + kval) % 53];
            state.spare[53] = state.deck[53];
            if (state.a != 53)
                state.a = (state.a + 53 - kval) % 53;
            if (state.b != 53)
                state.b = (state.b + 53 - kval) % 53;
            tmp = state.deck;
            state.deck = state.spare;
            state.spare = tmp;
        if (verbose) {
            print_deck();
            printf(" after %c\n", *key);
        }
        }
    }
    /* These are touched by the keying: fix them. */
    lastout = 100; cocount = 0;
}
```

So the error is in the line of the `for` loop where key is iterating -- what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: Three things - first, give the extra error in the question.  "An error" is not useful.  Second, give enough code that we see the variable declerations.  Knowing the types is important.  Third, it is essential you provide an explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: error is:     Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048ff3 in key_deck (key=0x0) at c1.c:210
210     for (; *key != '\0'; key++) {
(gdb)

Comment: Why did you post [the exact same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778906/error-in-c-code), rather than editing that one?

Comment: i didnt know whether i can edit that one. sorry for that am new her in stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling your function with a NULL pointer as a parameter. You can see this in the error message you got:

```
... in key_deck (key=0x0) ...
```

Comment: It means that wherever you are calling the `key_deck` function, you need to pass in a valid string.

Answer (score 1):

In your error message, you can see that you are passing NULL to the function

```
key_deck(key=0x0)
```

The error is actually in the caller.